# xorg, xrandr, 4 monitors and two nvidia graphics cards. Doesn't work in desired configuration

Tags: linux, nvidia, xorg

## What I have

- Two video cards. nvidia 1050 and nvidia 1050 Ti
- Four monitors. One is 4k, one is Full HD and two are 1920x1200. The last two are in portrait mode.

My monitors are placed like this:
[image]

nvidia-smi:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.28       Driver Version: 455.28       CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 43%   53C    P0    N/A /  75W |   1178MiB /  4034MiB |      6%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:08:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   28C    P8    N/A /  65W |      6MiB /  2000MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A    160537      G   /usr/bin/X                       1016MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    160872      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files        6MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    161444      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files      107MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    163168      G   kitty                               2MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    160537      G   /usr/bin/X                          4MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    160872      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files        0MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    161444      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files        0MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A    163168      G   kitty                               0MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## How it works now

All monitors are connected to the 1050 Ti. Works. The configuration is like this:

- xorg:

```cpp
# Managed by ansible. Editing is useless
# Sheridan
      
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Device_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107_"
  Driver     "nvidia"
  VendorName "NVidia Corporation"
  BoardName  "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107)"
  Option     "NoRenderExtension"    "off"
  Option     "IndirectMemoryAccess" "on"
  Option     "IgnoreEDID"           "off"
  Option     "UseEDID"              "on"
  Option     "NoLogo"               "off"
  Option     "RandRRotation"        "on"
  Option     "MultiGPU"             "off"
  Option     "SLI"                  "off"
  Option     "AllowSHMPixmaps"      "on"
  BusID      "PCI:01:00:0"
EndSection

      
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Device_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050__gp107_"
  Driver     "nvidia"
  VendorName "NVidia Corporation"
  BoardName  "GeForce GTX 1050 (GP107)"
  Option     "NoRenderExtension"    "off"
  Option     "IndirectMemoryAccess" "on"
  Option     "IgnoreEDID"           "off"
  Option     "UseEDID"              "on"
  Option     "NoLogo"               "off"
  Option     "RandRRotation"        "on"
  Option     "MultiGPU"             "off"
  Option     "SLI"                  "off"
  Option     "AllowSHMPixmaps"      "on"
  BusID      "PCI:08:00:0"
EndSection
        
# center: LG 27UL500-W -> 3840x2160@60
# first: NVidia Corporation GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107) @ DP-0
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier    "Monitor_lg_27ul500_w_first_dp_0"
  VendorName    "LG"
  ModelName     "27UL500-W"
  Option        "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "Screen_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107__lg_27ul500_w_first_dp_0"
  Device       "Device_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107_"
  Monitor      "Monitor_lg_27ul500_w_first_dp_0"
  DefaultDepth  24
  SubSection   "Display"
    Depth       24
  EndSubSection
EndSection
        
# top: LG 22MP55 -> 1920x1080@60
# first: NVidia Corporation GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107) @ DVI-D-0
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier    "Monitor_lg_22mp55_first_dvi_d_0"
  VendorName    "LG"
  ModelName     "22MP55"
  Option        "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "Screen_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107__lg_22mp55_first_dvi_d_0"
  Device       "Device_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107_"
  Monitor      "Monitor_lg_22mp55_first_dvi_d_0"
  DefaultDepth  24
  SubSection   "Display"
    Depth       24
  EndSubSection
EndSection
        
# left: Iiyama ProLite XU2395WSU-B1 -> 1920x1200@60
# first: NVidia Corporation GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107) @ HDMI-1
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier    "Monitor_iiyama_prolite_xu2395wsu_b1_first_hdmi_1"
  VendorName    "Iiyama"
  ModelName     "ProLite XU2395WSU-B1"
  Option        "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "Screen_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107__iiyama_prolite_xu2395wsu_b1_first_hdmi_1"
  Device       "Device_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107_"
  Monitor      "Monitor_iiyama_prolite_xu2395wsu_b1_first_hdmi_1"
  DefaultDepth  24
  SubSection   "Display"
    Depth       24
  EndSubSection
EndSection
        
# right: Iiyama ProLite XU2395WSU-B1 -> 1920x1200@60
# first: NVidia Corporation GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (GP107) @ HDMI-0
Section "Monitor"
  Identifier    "Monitor_iiyama_prolite_xu2395wsu_b1_first_hdmi_0"
  VendorName    "Iiyama"
  ModelName     "ProLite XU2395WSU-B1"
  Option        "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
  Identifier   "Screen_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107__iiyama_prolite_xu2395wsu_b1_first_hdmi_0"
  Device       "Device_nvidia_corporation_geforce_gtx_1050_ti__gp107_"
  Monitor      "Monitor_iiyama_prolite_xu2395wsu_b1_first_hdmi_0"
  DefaultDepth  24
  SubSection   "Display"
    Depth       24
  EndSubSection
EndSection
```

- Xrandr initialization script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0

# center: LG 27UL500-W -> 3840x2160@60
# top: LG 22MP55 -> 1920x1080@60
# left: Iiyama ProLite XU2395WSU-B1 -> 1920x1200@60
# right: Iiyama ProLite XU2395WSU-B1 -> 1920x1200@60


xrandr --verbose --dpi 96 \
    --output "DP-0" --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60  --primary  \
    --output "DVI-D-0" --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60  --above "DP-0"  \
    --output "HDMI-1" --mode 1920x1200 --rate 60  --left-of "DP-0" --rotate right \
    --output "HDMI-0" --mode 1920x1200 --rate 60  --right-of "DP-0" --rotate left \
```

At startup, Xs receive information about cards and monitors. Further, when the window manager starts, the xrandr initialization script is executed and the monitors are deployed and aligned in the positions I need.

## What I want

- Connect 4k monitor to 1050 Ti
- Connect other monitors to 1050

**That is, I want to distribute the load between two video cards**

## What i tried

Switching three monitors to the second video card.

### xrandr

Changing the initialization script does not give results. xrandr doesn't want to rotate monitors. The error is this: `xrandr: output HDMI-1-0 cannot use rotation "right" reflection "none"` Moreover, if i remove the rotation option, the monitors will not start anyway. Active only 4k monitor connected to the main graphics card.

- Xrandr initialization script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0

# center: LG 27UL500-W -> 3840x2160@60
# top: LG 22MP55 -> 1920x1080@60
# left: Iiyama ProLite XU2395WSU-B1 -> 1920x1200@60
# right: Iiyama ProLite XU2395WSU-B1 -> 1920x1200@60


xrandr --verbose --dpi 96 \
    --output "DP-0" --mode 3840x2160 --rate 60  --primary  \
    --output "DVI-D-1-0" --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60  --above "DP-0"  \
    --output "HDMI-1-0" --mode 1920x1200 --rate 60  --left-of "DP-0" --rotate right \
    --output "DP-1-1" --mode 1920x1200 --rate 60  --right-of "DP-0" --rotate left \
```

- [xorg.log](https://pastebin.com/LSk4UPXv)

### nvidia-settings

I also tried to configure the xorg.conf using nvidia-settings. Monitors initialize correctly and side monitors rotate correctly. But when i launch opengl applications (for example, [kitty](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/)), the interface starts to slow down. Switching between desktops/windows starts to slow down a lot (a few seconds to switch). At the same time, `nvidia-smi dmon` shows that 1050 is loaded at 100%:

```
# gpu   pwr gtemp mtemp    sm   mem   enc   dec  mclk  pclk
# Idx     W     C     C     %     %     %     %   MHz   MHz
    0     -    57     -     7     9     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     4     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -     7     9     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     4     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -     7     9     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     4     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -    10    11     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     5     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -    11    13     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     4     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -     7     9     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     5     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -    11    14     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     4     0     0  3504  1657
    0     -    57     -     7     9     0     0  3504  1303
    1     -    52     -   100     6     0     0  3504  1657
```

- xorg.conf:

```cpp
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 455.28

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 1200 1080
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 1200 0
    Screen      2  "Screen2" 0 1080
    Screen      3  "Screen3" 5040 1080
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from data in "/etc/conf.d/gpm"
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics LG HDR 4K"
    HorizSync       135.0 - 135.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 61.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LG Electronics 22MP55"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PL2395W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 89.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PL2395W"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 89.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050"
    BusID          "PCI:8:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050"
    BusID          "PCI:8:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050"
    BusID          "PCI:8:0:0"
    Screen          2
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNCCompatible=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen2"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor2"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=right}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen3"
    Device         "Device3"
    Monitor        "Monitor3"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-3"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

- [xorg log](https://pastebin.com/VPDD1CNS)

OS: Gentoo linux

Package versions:

```
[ebuild   R    ] x11-base/xorg-server-1.20.8-r1:0/1.20.8::gentoo  USE="ipv6 (libglvnd) systemd udev wayland xorg -debug -dmx -doc (-elogind) -kdrive -libressl -minimal (-selinux) -static-libs -suid -unwind -xcsecurity -xephyr -xnest -xvfb" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R    ] x11-apps/xrandr-1.5.1::gentoo  0 KiB
[ebuild   R    ] x11-drivers/nvidia-drivers-455.28-r1:0/455::gentoo  USE="X driver gtk3 kms (libglvnd) multilib tools uvm wayland -compat -static-libs" ABI_X86="32 (64) (-x32)" 0 KiB
[ebuild   R    ] x11-base/xorg-x11-7.4-r3::gentoo  USE="fonts" 0 KiB
```

Can you please tell me what else I can try? What have I forgotten? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Why don't you physically plug the monitors to the cards you want to associate? Why this post is not a superuser one instead of stackoverflow?

Comment: 1. I physically connect monitors, more on that in the "What i tried" paragraph. 2. Yes, you are right. I should have gone there.

Comment: what is not clear is "the consequences of what you tried", you might want to add details on how what you tried (reconnecting the monitors for instance).

Comment: VirtuMVP or similar might help you (https://superuser.com/questions/760493/is-it-possible-to-use-a-nvidia-gpu-to-render-graphics-if-the-monitor-is-connecte).

Comment: i tryed via xrandr and via nvidia-settings (subheadings)